# pandoc generates a pdf from a markdown file that truncates and looses characters inside blocks ``` ... ```

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Under *Debian 10* and for a long time, with various versions of *Pandoc*, I'm generating a *pdf* file from a *markdown* document, using this command :

```sh
pandoc elk.md -o elk.pdf
```

Inside the `elk.md` file there's this content under a ```bash block:

```sh
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

It generates a *pdf* with its line truncated :

[image]

An attempt to copy it, even by selecting it as a block, with one line above and below in the generated pdf, only retains this part of the text :

`echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sou`

and the original content is lost.
**What is the workaround to make *pandoc* working properly ?**

*Note 1* : adding line feed manually (with also additional `\` characters when necessary) like below :

```sh
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" \ 
  | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

won't be a solution.
If I add a larger source content in a block, I don't plan to check and edit all of its lines.

*Note 2* : In this sample, the markdown hasn't an header, so the *pdf* is generated with its (curious) default margin of 6 or 8 (?) centimeters. I usually add this header :

```
---
geometry: margin=2cm
classoption: fleqn
---
```

- To set its margin to 2 centimeters only.
- To allow better formatting of some latex content and allow the use of mathematic formula if needed, and also text color.

But this doesn't change the trouble I'm facing.

Comment: I think these links should be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323329, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179926. You could also try minted instead of listings, see https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/minted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tarleb : Thanks a lot. Among your links, I found the beginning of a solution that improves greatly the situation:

Adding a `header-includes` section to my markdown headers is simple and removes most of the disturbances.
(I read that other solutions like the `\lstset` definition were adding as many problems as solutions, and didn't try them).

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,commandchars=\\\{\}}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere}

geometry: margin=2cm
classoption: fleqn
---
```

[image]

**You can see the improvement!**
But... An extra character is inserted: `→` and if you copy paste the content, your clipboard contains :

```
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee
, →
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

1. three lines, instead of one
2. one of them is especially wrong, with a parasite comma coming from nowhere and an extra **→**

This could cause problem if you copy-paste this content.
(for instance, if you paste it on your terminal, confident, it would begin to execute: `echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee` before taking into account all that is needed to execute the command)

#### Explanation of commands

1. The `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}...` command redefines the Highlighting environment (which highlights code syntax) as a new "fancy" verbatim environment with special properties that allow it to break lines.
2. The `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}...` command does a similar thing for the verbatim environment (which is a different environment that has no syntax highlighting).